# Wrong parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to access to the title of this website: 
https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=broma
Actualy, I use BeautifulSoup, but when I access with this code results are empty ([]):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def generateSoup(my_url):
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()   
    uClient.close()
    return soup(page_html,"lxml")

page_soup = generateSoup('https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=broma')
containers = page_soup.findAll('a',{'class':'ng-binding'})
print(containers)
```

If you could correct my code or give me another library that I can work with, I would be very grateful for your help.

Thanks for all.

Edit: The problem is that the HTML WebSite not have this element:
[Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTxJt.png)

Comment: Excuse me. I forgot to make it clear that what I need is the title 'Annual Reports of Education, Health and Sport 9781329899971' (really it's the link, but with the title at the moment it works for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website use AJAX to display the result,you can find the AJAX request to get the JSON result.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

def generateJson(my_url):
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    return json.loads(page_html.decode("utf-8"))

page_json = generateJson('https://zenodo.org/api/records/?page=1&size=20&q=broma')
print(page_json["hits"]["hits"][0]["metadata"]["title"])
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. The problem is when I want the tittle 'Annual Reports of Education, Health and Sport 9781329899971' I can´t find with the line containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'ng-binding'})

Comment: Print page_soup  object to console,you can found there is no div which class is ng-binding.Because the website use AJAX to generate the result.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I´m going try to get the link of the tittle.